# How to display all data from different pages of html table to excel using jquery table2Excel or tableHTMLExport.js?

Tags: jquery

I want to export html table to excel using tableHTMLExport.js, I just tried following code

```
$("#tblDetails").[tableHTMLExport][1]({ 
  exclude:".noExl", 
  type: "csv", 
  filename: "sample.csv" 
});
```

This code export html table to excel,but it is not exporting heading when I export table with different pages.

Waiting for your valuable reply.

Thank you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noP1q.png)

Comment: For a valuable reply we need valuable information. I guess the tblDetails contains only the table body and not the header. But as I said. Its just a guess on missing information how you html looks liks

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff Thanks for the reply, I am binding my my table dynamically. My real  issue is when i export entire jquery datatable with pagination to excel it is not showing header in that table.I added screenshot of excel sheet. Can you please help me to solve this issue.